# spadminV4 which could not be contacted in deployment

Tags: powershell, deployment, server-farm

I have Sharepoint 2013 and Powershell deployment.

I execute muy ps1 script in SPS01 machine.
Farm servers are SPS01, SPS02, SPS03, SPS04.
User for deploy is UserInstallerMoss , it's Farm Administrator and only local Administrator in SPS01, not in others servers.

I call this function:

```
function RestartTimerFarm
{
    Write-Host -f Green Restarting OWSTIMER instances on Farm
    $farm = Get-SPFarm
    $farm.TimerService.Instances | foreach {$_.Stop();$_.Start();}
}
```

I get this error when its call to Stop method:

**This operation uses the SharePoint Administration service (spadminV4), which could not be contacted.  If the service is stopped or disabled, start it and try the operation again.)**

Now, I set UserInstallerMoss as local Administrator in SPS01, SPS02, SPS03, SPS04.

I get this error:

**This operation uses the SharePoint Administration service (spadminV4), which could not be contacted.  If the service is stopped or disabled, start it and try the operation again.)**

But if I execute WMI and Get-SPServer cmdlet all is OK

```
$servers=Get-SPServer | where {$_.role -ne "Invalid" }
        foreach ($server in $servers)
        {
            $serverName = $server.Name
            WriteTrace("Server in Farm... " + $serverName)

            CheckRemoteServiceStatus -Machine $serverName -Name "SPAdminV4" -Status "Running"

            WriteTrace("Restarting SPTimerV4 service in server... " + $serverName)

            $result = (Get-WmiObject -computer $serverName Win32_Service -Filter "Name='SPTimerV4'").InvokeMethod("StopService",$null)
            Start-Sleep -seconds 2
            $result = (Get-WmiObject -computer $serverName Win32_Service -Filter "Name='SPTimerV4'").InvokeMethod("StartService",$null)

            WriteTrace("SPTimerV4 service restarted in server " + $serverName)
        }
```

Comment: Are you running the commands on the server which runs the Central Administration? This error message could appear if commands are executed elsewhere.

Comment: From my findings the $farm.TimerService.Instances doesn't implement start() or stop(), so this shouldn't work at all. Could you please explain first what you are trying to achieve with your script?

Comment: I want restart Timer Service (SPtimerv4) in ALL servers in FARM. About Stop-Start : http://serverfault.com/a/556058

Answer (score 1):

Open sharepoint management shell as administrator then execute the command , it is working for me.